# Parallel.ForEach: How to block the main thread until all the parallel task finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

In the following scenario: can we block the main thread to begin to perform step 3 until step 2 finished?
I'm talking about C#

```
//step 1: some tasks
/*
*/

//step 2: perform some sub tasks in parallel.
Parallel.ForEach(X, x => Foo(x));

//step 3: Some other task
//Can we begin to perform step 3 until all sub tasks in step 2 finished???
```

Comment: `Parallel.ForEach` will wait.

Answer (score 1):

That should be the default behaviour. Put it in a console app with a console.writeline after it to prove it if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Task class to create the "tasks" you mentioned, probably try [Task.WaitAll(Task[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: He isn't using the `Task` class, he's using the `Parallel` class. This doesn't provide an answer to the question.